# GWT version differences

Tags: gwt

I am new to GWT. Just wondering to find differences in various releases of GWT ? I am not able to find differences in net even. Any references? links?

Anyhelp would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Priya.R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Release Notes for GWT](http://code.google.com/intl/en/webtoolkit/release-notes.html) is probably what you looking for.